# Show name of a country in three fields

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table called **Principal** with these columns:

- Person_ID
- Country1_ID
- Country2_ID
- Country3_ID

And I have another table called **Countries** with these columns:

- ID
- Country_Name

I need make a select that shows the Person_ID and the name of the three countries.
I have try with INNER JOIN, but always give me the same country in the three fields.

```
SELECT Principal.Person_ID, Countries.Country_Name AS Country1, Countries.Country_Name AS Country2, Countries.Country_Name AS Country3 
FROM
    (Countries
    INNER JOIN Principal
    ON Countries.ID = Principal.Country1_ID OR Countries.ID = Principal.Country2_ID  OR Countries.ID = Principal.Country3_ID);
```

What is the right SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get you want you want. It returns blank when a country does not match.

```
SELECT Principal.Person_ID
,(SELECT ISNull(Countries.Country_Name,'') FROM Countries WHERE Principal.Country1_ID OR Countries.ID ) AS Country1
,(SELECT ISNull(Countries.Country_Name,'') FROM Countries WHERE Principal.Country2_ID OR Countries.ID ) AS Country2
,(SELECT ISNull(Countries.Country_Name,'') FROM Countries WHERE Principal.Country3_ID OR Countries.ID ) AS Country3;
```

A merge might work better but I'm not so familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks, I have try the SELECT, and this works for me:
SELECT Principal.Person_ID
,(SELECT ISNull(Countries.Country_Name,'') FROM Countries WHERE Principal.Country1_ID = Countries.ID ) AS Country1
,(SELECT ISNull(Countries.Country_Name,'') FROM Countries WHERE Principal.Country2_ID = Countries.ID ) AS Country2
,(SELECT ISNull(Countries.Country_Name,'') FROM Countries WHERE Principal.Country3_ID = Countries.ID ) AS Country3
FROM Principal;